# MySQL using up all RAM and SWAP in group replication settings

Tags: linux, mysql

I am using MySQL 8.0.18 in a group replication (multi-master) infrastructure. There are currently 4 master servers connected to each other and everything seems to be working fine but over the course of around 2 weeks all mysqld process on all servers uses up all the swap. ram usage stays at 800Mb as I suspect innodb_log_buffer_size is doing its job.

Server Specs:

Debian 10

1Gb RAM

3GB SWAP

20GB ssd

Mysql.cnf:

max_connections=20

innodb_log_buffer_size=800M

key_buffer_size=50M

super_read_only=off

gtid_mode = ON

enforce_gtid_consistency = ON

master_info_repository = TABLE

relay_log_info_repository = TABLE

binlog_checksum = NONE

log_slave_updates = ON

log_bin = binlog

binlog_format = ROW

transaction_write_set_extraction = XXHASH64

loose-group_replication_bootstrap_group = OFF

loose-group_replication_start_on_boot = OFF

loose-group_replication_ssl_mode = REQUIRED

loose-group_replication_recovery_use_ssl = 1

loose-group_replication_unreachable_majority_timeout=80

loose-group-replication-autorejoin-tries=2015

loose-group-replication-transaction-size-limit=0

Related OS config:

vm.swappiness=5

How do I make mysql stop using so much swap?

Comment: Dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/261376/mysql-using-up-all-ram-and-swap-in-group-replication-settings

Answer (score 0):

You are squeezing all this into 1.0GB?

- The OS
- `mysqld`
- `innodb_log_buffer_size` (0.8GB)
- `key_buffer_size=50M`, even though MyISAM is gone

No wonder it is swapping.

Go back to the default (8M) for `innodb_log_buffer_size`.  That may be enough to fix your problem.

Comment: Appreciate your advise will try it out but can you let me know why it's swapping?

Comment: Also the default for innodb_log_buffer_size in mysql8 is 16MB

Comment: @Ken - OK, 16MB; but not 800MB -- that led to swapping.

Comment: The correct answer was to purge bin logs using option like `expire_logs_days`

Comment: @Ken - No. -- `innodb_log_buffer_size` impacts RAM usage. Excessive RAM usage leads to swap. `expire_logs_days` controls files on disk -- nothing to do with RAM or swap.